# C# For Loop How to Display Only Matching Values

Tags: c#, list, loops, for-loop, if-statement

My assignment is to create a string list that has at least two matching values and then to prompt the user to input one of those values and then I am to display the index or indices of that value entered.

I seem to have figured out how to get the desired indices to show, but I also need to have a statement in the event the value entered is not in the list and when I do an else, it messes things up. Looking for some help on this!

So this does what I want but without the else statement:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> mprovinces = new List<string> { "Nova Scotia", "New Brunswick", "Prince Edward Island", "Nova Scotia" };
    Console.WriteLine("Enter one of the following maritime provinces: \nNova Scotia, \nNew Brunswick, \nPrince Edward Island\n");
    string input2 = Console.ReadLine();


    for (int i = 0; i < mprovinces.Count; i++)
    {
        bool match = mprovinces[i] == input2;

        if (match)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
}
```

But when I add an else statement and I enter a value that is in the list it provides more data than I want:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> mprovinces = new List<string> { "Nova Scotia", "New Brunswick", "Prince Edward Island", "Nova Scotia" };
    Console.WriteLine("Enter one of the following maritime provinces: \nNova Scotia, \nNew Brunswick, \nPrince Edward Island\n");
    string input2 = Console.ReadLine();


    for (int i = 0; i < mprovinces.Count; i++)
    {
        bool match = mprovinces[i] == input2;

        if (match)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, this is not in the list");
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by more data than you need? If you want to end the loop when it goes on else statement use break; to come out of the loop

Comment: This is the best time -- when you start learning to program -- to learn [how to step through code in the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour).

Comment: For the prompt, may I suggest `Console.WriteLine("Enter one of the following maritime provinces:\n" + String.Join("\n", mprovinces));`

Comment: madreflection that's right!  I get that, so I tried some "else if" and tried to say (!match) but that didn't work either because it is still going through each time.  So would I put that statement outside of my loop somehow?  Or should I be using a different loop, like a do/while?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Joel.  I've adjusted my prompt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "Sorry" message is inside of the for loop you will show it for EVERY index that does not exactly match your input2. You need to pull the match value out of the for loop and check it once.

```
var matchIndex = -1; // can never get a -1 so it's a good default to check for later

for (int i = 0; i < mprovinces.Count; i++)
{
    if (mprovinces[i] == input2)
    {
        matchIndex = i;
        break; // break out of loop
    }
}

if (matchIndex >= 0) // again a valid index will never be below 0
{
    Console.WriteLine("Index: " + matchIndex);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, this is not in the list");
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what you want to show. If you only want to show the FIRST index that matches then the above code will work. If you want to show EVERY index that matches then this would work.

EDIT: I have changed this function to not use a string to keep track of the list. It just shows the matching indexes as they appear.

```
bool matchExists = false;

for (int i = 0; i < mprovinces.Count; i++)
{
    if (mprovinces[i] == input2)
    {
        matchExists = true;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}

if (matchExists == false) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, this is not in the list");
}
```

Comment: Don't use a string to store a list. Use an actual list type, such as `List<int>`.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but since this looks like a beginner code with a very simple output I figured not to add too much extra code into the mix. Not sure they would have been introduced to lists yet.

Comment: A beginner should not be pointed in this direction. Lists are simple enough. Too often, this leads to string concatenation hell because they think it's "okay".

Comment: Considering that the question has a `List<string>` variable declared in the very first statement in `Main`, I'm going to assume that they've at least received some mention.

Comment: YES!  Your edit is what I was trying to do, but was getting confused because we had only been taught using the bool with while and I wasn't sure how to make it work with a for loop.  Thank you so much everyone for their feedback and advice!

Comment: @Heather: A `for` is mostly just syntactical sugar (with some special variable scoping thrown in, at least in C#). *Your* `for` loop is effectively the same as `int i = 0; while (i < mprovinces.Count) { /*contents of the loop block*/ i++; }` (except the `i` variable is inaccessible after the `for` loop, but very accessible after the `while` loop, i.e. variable scoping).

Comment: @madreflection I was trying with a while loop thinking it would be the shortest distance to the end result, but I couldn't seem to figure out how to get it to provide more than one value...? My instructions required me to have two matching strings in my list so that if the user input that it would display both indices. Do I still use my boolean when using while? Is the only difference between the while and for is that the while makes the i variable global?

Comment: @Heather.: Close. Not *global*, just available outside the loop where it was declared. If you do `if (...) { int i = 0; while (...) {... i++;} }`, the `i` variable, being declared within the `if` block, would not be visible outside of that. Read up on "variable scope". Outside of that, a `while` loop gives you more flexibility on what you can do. You may then wonder "why would I ever use a 'for' loop?" Consistency: It's an extremely common pattern, so it's easier to get it right within that framework and then you and others will recognize and understand code quicker than the equivalent...

Comment: ...`while` loop. Limited variable scope: "limitations" may sound bad but you want to avoid variables that "live" too long before or after they're needed, not to reduce resource use (well, sometimes because of that, too), but because of anti-patterns such as "action at a distance" (affecting a variable from somewhere unrelated, making it difficult to determine the reason for a behavior). As for whether to use a boolean, change it so that you're not using it and see what happens. Do the science. There's nothing magical in programming, which is why the word "codes" bothers me so much...

Comment: ...when programming code is an uncountable noun, like how you add water to water and you still have water, not "waters". On some level, everything is examinable. You try it, you examine it, you keep what works and rewrite what doesn't (and sometimes you rewrite what does work for the fun of it).